# Booting ubuntu falure: error: attempt to read or write outside of "hd0"

Tags: boot

This is my first ever try with Ubnuntu. I installed dual boot with windows xp. When booting up on ACER Aspire 9101 I get the following message.

```
 Booting ubuntu falure: error: attempt to read or write outside of "hd0"
```

Can anybody help? I am not an ubuntu expert.

thx /anton

Comment: Run the command `sudo fdisk -lu` and add the output to your question.